# Deleting files in a directory, keeping files created on a certain day of the month unless it's the weekend, then keeping files from following Monday

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script that deletes all files in a directory older than a specified number of days, but I want to keep files created on the 15th day of the month as an archive. I also need the day of the month to shift to the following Monday in months where the 15th falls on a weekend (keeping files creates on the 16th or 17th instead). I came up with a dirty way to do it, but hoping to get some input on a cleaner approach.

Here's my working code:

```
import datetime
import time
import os 

for root, _, filenames in os.walk(directory_to_clean):
    for filename in filenames:
        file_path = f"{root}/{filename}"
        created = os.path.getctime(file_path)
        created_day = datetime.fromtimestamp(created).strftime("%d")
        if created < time.time()-2592000:   ### deleting older than 30 days
            day_of_week = datetime.fromtimestamp(created).weekday()

            #getting rid of anything with a creation day before the 15th or after the 17th, or if 16th/17th and not a Monday, or if 15th but on a weekend 
            if 15 <= int(created_day) <= 17 or (created_day == '16' and not weekday == 0) or (created_day == '17' and not weekday == 0) or (created_day == '15' and weekday > 4):
                os.remove(file_path)
```

Comment: `datetime` should have `.day` which gives `integer` and you don't need `strftime("%d")`. `datetime` has also `timedelta(days=30)` which you chould use instead of `2592000` and then you can use `datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)`. and safer is to compare `year.month.day` instead of only `day`

Comment: safer `file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)` it work correctly on all systems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems OK but `datetime` has some functions to make it cleaner

If you convert timestamp to datetime

```
created_datetime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(created_timestamp)
```

then you can get day directly as integer

```
created_day = created_datetime.day
```

You can also get `date` without `time` to compare with other `date`

```
created_date = created_datetime.date()
```

Today date (without `time`) you can get with

```
today = datetime.date.today()
```

or

```
today = datetime.datetime.now().date()
```

and then you can get 30 days before using

```
before_30_days = today - datetime.timedelta(days=30)
```

or

```
one_day = datetime.timedelta(days=1)

before_30_days = today - 30*one_day
```

And you can compare date (without `time`)

```
created_date < before_30_days
```

---

```
import datetime
import time
import os 

# calculate only once 
today = datetime.date.today()
before_30_days = today - datetime.timedelta(days=30)
#one_day = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
#before_30_days = today - 30*one_day

for root, _, filenames in os.walk('test'):
    for filename in filenames:
        file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
        created_timestamp = os.path.getctime(file_path)
        created_datetime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(created_timestamp)
        created_date = created_datetime.date()
        created_day = created_datetime.day
        #print(created_day)
        
        if created_date < before_30_days:   ### deleting older than 30 days
            day_of_week = created_datetime.weekday()    # monday = 0
            #day_of_week = created_datetime.isoweekday() # monday = 1
            #print(created_date, '|', day_of_week)

            # getting rid of anything with a creation day before the 15th or after the 17th,
            # or if 16th/17th and not a Monday, or if 15th but on a weekend 
            if (15 <= created_day <= 17
                or (created_day == 16 and not weekday == 0)
                or (created_day == 17 and not weekday == 0)
                or (created_day == 15 and weekday > 4)):
                #os.remove(file_path)
                print(created_date, '|', day_of_week, '|', file_path)
```

Answer (score 1):

I took a different approach and broke things up a bit into smaller functions.  (I also may have misread your logic for which files to keep).  I tried to get the removal logic down a check for older than X days and NOT created on the day of the month to reserve:

```
import os 
import sys
import datetime

def get_created_info(file_path: str) -> tuple:
    created_timestamp = os.path.getctime(file_path)
    created_datetime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(created_timestamp)
    return created_datetime.date(), created_datetime.day

def get_day_to_keep(today) -> int:
    target = datetime.datetime(today.year, today.month, 15)
    if target.weekday() == 5: # saturday, so forward 2 days
        target=datetime.datetime(today.year, today.month, 17)

    if target.weekday() == 6: # sunday, so forward 1 day
        target=datetime.datetime(today.year, today.month, 16)

    return target.day # return day of month


def remove_old_files(today, number_of_days, path_to_search:str):
    age_in_days = today - datetime.timedelta(days=number_of_days)
    day_to_keep = get_day_to_keep(today)
    for root, _, filenames in os.walk(path_to_search):
        for filename in filenames:
            file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
            if not os.path.isdir(file_path):
                created_date, created_day = get_created_info(file_path)

                # remove if too old and NOT created on day to keep
                if created_date < age_in_days and created_day != day_to_keep:   
                    #os.remove(file_path)
                    print('X - removed: ', created_date, '|', created_day, '|', file_path)
                else:
                    print('OK - keep: ', created_date, '|', created_day, '|', file_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ###########################################################
    # modify the 'path_to_search' variable or pass in a command
    # line parameter that represents the path to search for 
    # files to remove.
    #
    # Usage: 
    #   python script.py /path/to/dir
    #   -- or --
    #   python script.py
    #
    ###################################################
    path_to_search='/tmp/samples'
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        path_to_search=sys.argv[1]
    
    remove_old_files(datetime.date.today(), 30, path_to_search)
```